# Is there an function for change item properties?

Tags: c#

I want to change an item properties with function. I can do that with Python but how can I do on C# Language? I added a sample on c# below but this is not working:

I'm working on Visual Studio 2015 and I use C# language.

```cs
static void ChangeText(object itemName, string setText)
{

    itemName.Text = setText;

}
```

or

```cs
static void ChangeVisibility(object itemName, string VisibleOrNot)
{
   if(VisibleOrNot == true)
   {
     itemName.Visible = true;

   }
   else
   {
     itemName.Visible = false;
   }     
}
```

Comment: Your code will not compile, just follow compiler error to make code compile.

Comment: `string` does not have a `Text` or `Visible` property!  Are you trying to do something in a winforms `TextBox`?

Comment: Yes @Minijack, I try to change property an item. This can be a text box or label.

Comment: @Sedat seeing your most recent edit, what is `itemName` is is the property you want to change or the object you want to change?
If it is the object, then pass it as its actual type (e.g. `TextBox`) rather then an `object`

Comment: Use `Control` instead of `object` as parameter, if you're dealing with controls. Of couse, if you want to change the Visible property, you use a `bool` parameter, not a string, so `itemName.Visible = VisibleOrNot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are trying to set the visibility of control. Change the type of itemName to Control, and type of VisibleOrNot to bool like below.

```
ChangeVisibility(Control itemName, bool VisibleOrNot)
{
    if (VisibleOrNot == true)
    {
        itemName.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        itemName.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talk about this?

```
public class Product
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}

static void SetValue(Object p, string propertyName, Object value)
{
    p.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(p, value);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var p = new Product();
    SetValue(p, "Code", "A");

    Console.WriteLine(p.Code);

    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but no. I'm talking about C# Form items properties.

Comment: it's same, all class in C# are inherit from Object.